# Property vs Instance Variable

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between an "instance variable" and a "property" in objective-c / cocoa / cocoa-touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843632/is-there-a-difference-between-an-instance-variable-and-a-property-in-objectiv)

What is a case in Objective C where you would want to use an instance variable vs property?  Can someone provide a real-life example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between an "instance variable" and a "property" in objective-c / cocoa / cocoa-touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843632/is-there-a-difference-between-an-instance-variable-and-a-property-in-objectiv) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719788

Answer (score 99, accepted):

An instance variable is unique to a class. By default, only the class and subclasses can access it. Therefore, as a fundamental principal of object-oriented programming, instance variables (ivars) are private—they are encapsulated by the class.

By contrast, a property is a public value that may or may not correspond to an instance variable. If you want to make an ivar public, you'd probably make a corresponding property. But at the same time, instance variables that you wish to keep private do not have corresponding properties, and so they cannot be accessed from outside of the class. You can also have a calculated property that does not correspond to an ivar.

Without a property, ivars can be kept hidden. In fact, unless an ivar is declared in a public header it is difficult to even determine that such an ivar exists.

A simple analogy would be a shrink-wrapped book. A property might be the `title`, `author` or hardcover vs. softcover. The "ivars" would be the actual contents of the book. You don't have access to the actual text until you own the book; you don't have access to the ivars unless you own the class.

---

More interestingly, properties are better integrated into the runtime. Modern 64-bit runtimes will generate an ivar for accessor properties, so you don't even need to create the ivar. Properties are in fact methods:

```
// This is not syntactically correct but gets the meaning across
(self.variable) == ([self variable];)
(self.variable = 5;) == ([self setVariable:5];)
```

For every property, there are two methods (unless the property is declared `readonly`, in which case there is only one): there is the *getter*, which returns the same type as the ivar and is of the same name as the ivar, as well as the *setter* (which is not declared with a `readonly` ivar); it returns void and its name is simply *set* prepended to the variable name.

Because they are methods, you can make dynamic calls on them. Using [`NSSelectorFromString()`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSSelectorFromString) and the various [`performSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) methods, you can make a very dynamic program with many possibilities.

Finally, properties are used extensively in Core Data and with [Key-Value Coding](http://cupsofcocoa.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/objective-c-lesson-13-key-value-coding/). Core Data is an advanced framework for storing data in a SQLite database while providing a clear Obj-C front-end; KVC is used throughout Core Data and is a dynamic way to access properties. It is used when encoding/decoding objects, such as when reading from XIBs.

Comment: You can declare properties in a class extension to keep them "private" while benefiting of the memory management encapsulation and boilerplate code elimination that they provide.

Comment: Yeah but what about ARC.. there's no more "memory management" needed, so is there still an advantage to use @property?

Comment: @VanDuTran: properties really aren't about memory management. They're 1/3 semantics, 2/3 functionality in terms of accessing values (and controlling that access). They also have runtime advantages, like I described in the second half of my post—you can't do that with ivars, because `@property` results in methods and the runtime system works with methods.

Comment: iVars doesn't do retain unless you manually do it.  Properties can retain it automatically.  Your prog could crash if a method returns a pointers that needs expects you to retain it, but the method releases it after.

Comment: Indeed! Hence the need to set/get by calling '_property' instead of 'self.property' within certain methods, as this is often the cause of bad access errors you see occasionally.

Comment: arent properties declared in .m private too?

Comment: Yes. Properties/ivars have changed a bit since I wrote this answer…now all properties come with implicit ivars (`@property var` also makes available the the ivar `_var`). Properties declared in the `.m` is now the 'best' way to create a private field

Comment: @FeifanZ, So should one use ivars anymore in 2015?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei AFAIK, with Swift you can't create an ivar without it being a "property" as well. With ObjC, there is no "should" or "shouldn't"; the reasons for either stated above are still valid, and it depends on how you want your code to work.

Comment: Refer this :- http://www.onestopios.com/tutorials/understanding-instance-variables-properties/

Comment: Excellent answer this answer is better than answers on the other question. AFAIK you are wrong about ivars in .h . They are accessible from outside of implementation. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577175/5175709 and kindly let us know what is right.

Comment: Why that `is not syntactically correct but gets the meaning across`? I thought `self.variable` and `[self variable];` are just equivalent?

Comment: @Clay what if I set my instance variables (ivars) public? then what's the purpose of @property?