# Declaration of variables in the class extension (anonymous category) vs Implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have seen dozens of people using declarations like this in their implementation files:

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@implementation ViewController
{
  UIPopoverController *popoverController;
      NSString *currentPick;
    ….
}
```

Is it a good way or shall I define properties in the class extenion like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentPick;
    ….
}
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize popoverController;
@synthesize currentPick;
...
```

I'm a lit a bit confused in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah sorry coming from Java hearing instace variable confused me, since translating into the terms of objective-c, properties would be the instance variables, in objective-c they are obviously not. The advantages are that defining properties in class extensions is that you can set the getter and/or the setter methods automatically.

Comment: Related: [Where to put ivars in modern ObjC?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13566862)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Property vs Instance Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057934/property-vs-instance-variable?lq=1)

The best way is to declare properties within your class extensions.