# Difference between declaring properties in interface

Tags: objective-c

Can someone tell me what is the difference between declaring a property in interface like this

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
  NSDate *timestamp;
}
@end
```

and

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *timestamp;
@end
```

and

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
  NSDate *timestamp;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *timestamp;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property vs Instance Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057934/property-vs-instance-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former is not a property at all. It's an instance variable declaration.

The latter is a property, which is a term for a getter/setter pair and their backing instance variable.

The instance variable that's synthesized for you will be prefixed with `_`. So if you look at `RootViewController` using the Objective C runtime APIs, you can see it actually has an ivar named `_timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing. I updated my code slightly, Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Nothing has really changed. Now you just have a combination of both cases. What's your question?