# UITextField, where to define it in a ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, viewcontroller

I have a couple of examples of code. What is the difference between defining the two text fields (A and B) inside the @interface ViewController {} and defining the two text fields outside of it? Thanks.

http://pastie.org/9083686

http://pastie.org/9083687

Comment: You declare ivars inside the braces and properties outside. Your second example would produce a syntax error by declaring the properties inside the braces.

Comment: Was the response from the other person (nmh) correct?

Comment: Originally, the code in the example had A and B as labels and C was a text field. The labels were inside the braces while the text field was outside (like in the second link, except A and B were labels). I was changing it so A and B became text fields so I am not sure I get why that is going to create a syntax error for those to be outside the braces. Are you saying a label is an ivar but a text field is a property? Why is that the case?

Comment: I think you should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719788/property-vs-instance-variable

Comment: Setters and getters just set or get an ivar's value...what is direct access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *a;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *b;
```

both **a** and **b** are iVars, but **a** does not have implicitly created setter/getter by default.
You can access **a** by doing something like

```
if (a.text.length == 0) { ... }
```

and we call it direct access.

but for **b**, we use *self.* to have an access to it.

```
if (self.b.text.length == 0) { ... }
```

By using *self.*, you are stating that you want to use setter/getter method to access **b**.

You can even choose not to use setter/getter by accessing **_b** (if you have not explicitly synthesized it) directly like below:

```
if (_b.text.length == 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Internal class ViewController can access to a

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
   UITextField *a; 
}
```

Outside class ViewController can access to a

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *a;
@end
```